# Crash after write to file in linux, is data written through in order?

Tags: linux, file

For example:
append 16KB to a file, then the program crash before appending finished.
Is it possible that there is a hole without data written, and data in that hole is undefined.
For example: the first 4KB is written, and the last 4KB is written, but the 8KB in the middle is not written.

Comment: Is the program multi-threaded?  Are you concerned about machine crashes or only application crashes (e.g. SIGSEGV)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I know the kernel would help flush if only application crashes, you may suppose the machine stops.